# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor'

Tags: python, import, module

I know this problem has been posted a thousand times but i feel like everything is fine in my project and environment (as my code was working for a week and suddenly without changes to it, it stopped working on these errors)

Can someone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it please? Re-installing packages doesn't work.

Using python 3.6.6

Code:

```
#Imports
import sys
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import datetime
from termcolor import colored
import openpyxl as xl
from colored import fg, bg, attr
```

Placing another import termcolor for example doesn't change anything.

[Python version and interpreter match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nooVc.png)

[Pip installed list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QApKx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "from"
Use only "import termcolor"

Comment: As you can see in my question this doesn't solve anything and it has been working for a week.

Answer (score 0):

Termcolor, if I am not mistaken, needs the command prompt pip install termcolor.

Hope this works!

Comment: As you can see from my pictures this is installed.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using the correct interpreter that `termcolor` was installed  with.

Comment: As you can see from te pictures this is the case.